# Getting Input of Date and storing in Django Admin

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-admin

I am trying to build an app where I am creating a form and getting different date inputs from user.

However I was able to capture the date on which the input was taken but not sure how can I capture the date which users give input of....for example just like date of birth or something.

I am writing down the code below wherever I have made the changes,

form1.html

```
<form method="POST" action="/form1/">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Security Stamp Date</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name= "stamp_date" required>
  </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>

  </form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
from inventory_app.models import Form1
import datetime
from .models import Form1 

if request.method == "POST":
   stamp_date = request.POST.get('stamp_date')
   form1 = Form1(stamp_date = datetime.date(stamp_date))
   form1.save()

return render(request, 'form1.html')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Form1(models.Model):
     stamp_date = models.DateField()
```

The error which I get after clicking the "Submit button" after inputting the date is:

[image]

After going to admin panel (http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/inventory_app/form1/) inside my app this is the error I get

[image]

Comment: run `makemigrations` and `migrate` command..because `stamp_date` not migrate properly..

Comment: I did that @Pradip.
I even deleted all the migrations and tried to make a fresh migrations but it didn't worked out

Comment: Even now I tried and it says that No changes detected.

Comment: yes this occurs often..clear your database and run again makemigrations and migrate(Alert : All data would be deleted)

Comment: How to completely delete the database ? can you tell me ?
I used to delete the migrations file but not the init file of migration folder.

Comment: Do not delete `__init__.py` file. Delete `db.sqlite3` file which is in your project level.(Alert : All data would be deleted)